# DOJO query pseudo elements

Tags: javascript, css, dojo

I have a DOM object `item` and I wish to query for the `::after` pseudo element of that DOM object using DOJO's query selector.

I've tried

```
    _getExpandableIcon: function(item) {
        return query(item + '::after')[0];
    },
```

And

```
    _getExpandableIcon: function(item) {
        return query('::after', item)[0];
    },
```

My dom object looks like

```
<li class="sos-side-navigation-item expandable">
    <div class="sos-side-navigation-item-icon">
        <span class="sos-icon sos-icon-currency-gbp"></span>
    </div>
    <div class="sos-side-navigation-item-name">
        Type Something
    </div>
    ::after
</li>
```

Comment: `:after` is not a `DOM` node, so, i don't this `dojo/query` can't select it and return it

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The default selector engine in dojo does not support pseudo selector.

> .class, #id, tag, and *, attribute selectors, and child (>),
>   descendant (space), and union (,) combinators. If the native selector
>   engine is, the engine does not support pseudo classes. [Ref](https://dojotoolkit.org/reference-guide/1.10/dojo/query.html).

But you can change the selector engine, for example, you can use [sizzle](https://sizzlejs.com/):

```
<script data-dojo-config="selectorEngine: 'sizzle/sizzle'" src="dojo/dojo.js">
</script>

define(["dojo/query!slick/Source/slick"], function(query){
  query(".someClass:custom-pseudo").style("color", "red");
});
```